# WCF using TLS and Secure Remote Password (SRP)

Tags: .net, wcf, srp-protocol

Secure Remote Password is described in RFC 5054, however I don't see any specific support for this in .NET or WCF. Has anyone come across this where it is baked into the .NET libraries. I realize OpenSSL is an option here but I'm trying to avoid third party libraries. Writing a custom version being completely fraught with danger is also completely out of the question.

Comment: HIi - I am facing the same question. Have you ever found anything? I find bits and pieces of code for .NET - Node/JS and Ruby have nice libraries that just work. I cannot work out how to do this on .NET Cryptographic libraries?

Comment: Bouncy Castle is an option, but there are now some other implementations too. Check out Wikipedia, they now have a page for it and some implementations are listed at the bottom.  The problem is that its really difficult to be sure the implementations are secure. .NET provides lots of libraries (really adds to the strength of the language) and I think they ought to consider this as an addition.

Comment: Yes I found BOuncy Castle shorlty after this. There is source code to so I may just extrract the stuff I need to avoid a 2mb DLL - I am targetting embedded on dotnet core so need to keep it small. But I did NOT want to roll my own SRP stuff. I'll just use the bouncy castle stuff. Also there is a way to use OpenSSL wrapper to do it but it sounds heavy and clunky